# Reftex compatibility with newclude

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode

I want to use RefTex with newclude. In particular I want Reftex to recognize \include* as a legitimate include file command. I've already added include* in Reftex include file command but it doesn't seem to effect anything. In particular I still get empty reference select buffer. When I change \include* to \include, it finds the references. How can I make Reftex recognize \include* ?

Comment: How did you customize `reftex-include-file-commands`?  It works for me if I eval `(setq reftex-include-file-commands '("include\\*?" "input"))` and then load the tex file (tested briefly, though).